# error in installing any file having dependency on JRE on ubuntu14.04

Tags: java, ubuntu

Whenever I try to install any file it proceeds will until it finds jre then this following message is displayed on the terminal

```
Setting up jre1.8.0-77 (1.8.077-1) ...
Unpacking JAR files...
    plugin.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_77/lib/plugin.pack
    javaws.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_77/lib/javaws.pack
    deploy.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_77/lib/deploy.pack
    rt.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_77/lib/rt.pack
    jsse.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_77/lib/jsse.pack
    charsets.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_77/lib/charsets.pack
    localedata.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_77/lib/ext/localedata.pack
    jfxrt.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_77/lib/ext/jfxrt.pack
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jre1.8.0-77.postinst: line 641: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package jre1.8.0-77 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
```

I did install jdk 1.8 still showing same error

tried installing conky manager showed this error
tried installing apache-2 showed this error
tried installing oracle showed this error
even when I tried to uninstall some file the uninstallation stopped as jre showed error

any help will be appreciable.

Comment: Do you have /usr/bin/update-alternatives directory on your machine?

Comment: @RaviTezu Yes i do have

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir -p /usr/sbin
ln -s /usr/bin/update-alternatives /usr/sbin/alternatives
```

After running the above commands, you can try the installation.

Comment: still not runningError: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_77/lib/ext/localedata.pack
 jfxrt.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_77/lib/ext/jfxrt.pack
update-alternatives: error: alternative ControlPanel can't be slave of java: it is a master alternative
dpkg: error processing package jre1.8.0-77 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jre1.8.0-77
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
`